# gradle can't download ua-parser file

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to test some jenkins job seed dsls and for that I needed to download in gradle all plugins jenkins had, one of them was blueocean and in my `build.gradle` I've got this line

```sh
    testPlugins 'io.jenkins.blueocean:blueocean:1.23.2'
```

and I get thrown this exception

```sh
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find ua_parser:ua-parser:1.3.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ua_parser/ua-parser/1.3.0/ua-parser-1.3.0.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ua_parser/ua-parser/1.3.0/ua-parser-1.3.0.jar
    - http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/ua_parser/ua-parser/1.3.0/ua-parser-1.3.0.pom
    - http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/ua_parser/ua-parser/1.3.0/ua-parser-1.3.0.jar
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/ua_parser/ua-parser/1.3.0/ua-parser-1.3.0.pom
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/ua_parser/ua-parser/1.3.0/ua-parser-1.3.0.jar
  Required by:
      project : > io.jenkins.blueocean:blueocean:1.23.2 > io.jenkins.blueocean:blueocean-rest-impl:1.23.2
```

I tried running with gradlew `4.8.1` and `6.0.1`

I tried addint the `ua-parser` to build.gradle

```sh
    compile group: 'ua_parser', name: 'ua-parser', version: '1.3.0'
```

I tried removing all gradle cache and refresh dependencies

```sh
rm -rf ~/.gradle/cache
./gradlew test --refresh-dependencies # or ./gradlew build ..
```

I disabled the vpn so it wasn't some firewall not allowing me to connect to the site, maybe I have some outdated gradle repository stored ? (I'm not familiar with gradle yet, so maybe something simple is escaping my sight)

---

EDIT 1:

I think this might be related to missing repository so tried adding new one by hand I found the `https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin` and tried add it to `settings.gradle`

```sh
sourceControl {
    gitRepository("https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin.git") {
        producesModule("org.gradle.blueocean:utilities")
    }
}
```

and then referencing in `build.gradle`

```sh
  dependencies { 
...
     implementation 'org.gradle.blueocean:utilities'
```

but doesn't seem to work, does anyone know how to add/where to search for gradle repositories (specifically with blueocean poms)

Answer (score 0):

had to add those lines in repositories in `build.gradle`

```sh
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/' }
     maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jenkins.blueocean' }
     maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ua_parser/ua-parser' }
     maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact' }
     maven { url 'https://maven.twttr.com/' }
```

Comment: I think you only needed the first and last the last ones

Comment: ie: not the mvnrepository ones

Comment: I'm running into an issue where 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/' keeps serving some 'landing' HTML page instead of the requested POM file, so gradle chokes on it with errors like:  `Could not resolve org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.70.
      > Could not parse POM http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-core/1.70/job-dsl-core-1.70.pom
         > The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".`  Some weird frog logo appears first when accessing the POM file url.